# Compute $PSP^{-1} y$ without computing matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-decomposition, similar-matrices

Let $P$ (symmetric) and $S$ be two matrices of size $N \times N$, and $y$ be a vector of size $N \times 1$. I would like to compute $PSP^{-1} y$ without computing $P^{-1}$ because, in my case, $P$ is an ill-conditioned matrix. I have tried to scale the matrix to reduce its condition number but it did not help. Since $P$ contains element ranging from $10^{-20}$ to $1$, approaches like LU and singular value decomposition also were not useful.

I am looking for a hint to approach this problem in a different way.

Comment: How big is P?  If it's a reasonable size, then do the inversion symbolically;  you might have to carry the symbolics all the way through.  The bad news is that your computer might have to work; the good news is that you don't have to :)

Comment: N=1000. By symbolically, do you mean parameterizing the matrix P? Not sure how can this be done with 10^6 /2 parameters.

Comment: You might try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix  and (a reference in that) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement   
Otherwise, I seem to remember something like this:  set Q=A-P,  P=A-Q ,   
then P^(-1)= I/(A-Q)  then  
P^(-1)=(A^-1)*1/(1-(Q/A)= (A^-1) sum((Q/A)^n,n,0..)  
It would be nice if A is the identity matrix but I think it should be close to a diagonal of Eigenvalues.  It's been too long for me to be accurate (or to expand).  But check into "Numerical Analysis" (or modern data reduction)  .  I think this might is quite old problem.

Comment: I tried using a ML "andisearch.com" that I have found useful (usually a bit down  the list).  It basically gives references without a lot of interpretation.  
Here is one paper  
https://www.math.ksu.edu/research/reu/reu2005-2008/2006/pdfs/dhall.pdf
The search term was "inverting an ill-conditioned matrix"  

Several other items came up.  Sorry if this is too late.  For some reason, I got an email tag for this problem.